# Matching numbers from two files using Linux

Tags: linux

Using a Linux command or script, I would like to compare data in two files.  The first file has a series of 7 numbers followed by a name on one line, with several lines of numbers and names in the file.  The numbers cannot repeat on the same line, but could be found in another line, and will be listed in order, on each line.

File1 example:

01 02 03 04 05 06 07 Name1

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 Name2

01 03 05 11 12 14 16 Name3

...

I want to know when one of the lines of numbers from File1 match another grouping of numbers from File2.  The numbers in File2 don't repeat and will be sorted in order.

File2 example:

01 02 03 04 05 11 12 13 14 15 16 18 20

As soon as a line of numbers from File1 match any of the numbers from File2, I would like a display of the line that matches, including the name.

Output example:

01 03 05 11 12 14 16 Name3

If there is no match, I would like to display "No Match" or similar.

I am new to Linux and script files and appreciate any and all help.  Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a line from File 2 to match File 1 as long as all the numbers appear at some point on the line in File 2?

Comment: If File2 just a single line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather easy to do with Awk.  Let's take this piecemeal.

```
NR==FNR { for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) a[$i]=1; next }
```

The `NR==FNR` condition is true when we are reading the first input file. We loop over the input fields, and assign a key in the associative array `a` to each.  This now contains the input fields from the first file (which we will make sure is `File2` when we run it).

On the lines from the other file, loop over the fields up to the second last (we skip the last field, which contains the identifier, like `Name2`).  If any value is not in `a`, abandon this line.

```
{ for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if (! ($i in a)) next }
```

Otherwise, print.

```
1
```

(The lone `1` is an Awk idiom which prints the input if we fall through to this part in the script.  It's a condition which is trivially true, with no action; the default action is to print the input line.)

Collecting everything together in a shell script snippet, we obtain

```
awk 'NR==FNR { for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) a[$i] = 1; next }
    { for (i=1; i<NF; i++) if (! ($i in a)) next } 1' File2 File1
```

This assumes that `File2` only contains a single line.  The capabilities of Awk will be a bit strained if you want to extend to multiple lines; at that point, maybe consider switching to Perl or Python (or whatever else you happen to be familiar with).  The attraction of Awk is that it is simple -- you can learn it in a day, and write good scripts in a week.

Comment: Beautiful! Way better than plain Bash =)

Comment: Perfect! This was a key final component to get my program to work fully.  I still have many things to learn and I'll add Awk to the top of my list.  @savanto thank you for your help too.  I agree, this worked better.  I appreciate it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This (rather ugly) bash script will produce the correct result on your given sample data:

```
# Read numbers against which to match from File2 into array.
read -a match_array <<< "$(cat File2)"

# Traverse each line in File1
while read -a line
do
  if [ "$line" != "" ]
  then

    # Counter for the number of matches
    match=0

    # Strip off the name on the end, leaving only numbers to match
    for n in "${line[@]:0:7}"
    do
      for m in "${match_array[@]}"
      do
        if [ "$n" == "$m" ]
        then
          # Successfully matched a number, increment counter.
          match=$(($match + 1))
        fi
      done

      # Correct number of matches
      if [ "$match" == "7" ]
      then
        echo ${line[@]}
      fi
    done
  fi
done < File1
```